# Diffrence in calculating same number

Tags: javascript, calculator, calculation

Today I encountered a bug which happens in computer calculation.
in JavaScript I used Math.pow(3,35) which should return the 3^35 or 50031545098999704
which should equivalent to 3^34 * 3 but the number I was getting was 50031545098999710

when I try Math.pow(3,34) * 3 I get the right number but for Math.pow(3,35) it just bugs out every time, and this problem is not only with javascript i tried other calculators as well but they are all returning the false valse.
Please if anyone got information about this issue let me know, thanks.

Comment: This is an inevitable consequence of storing decimal float numbers in binary.

Comment: With IEEE-754 double-precision binary floating point numbers (the kind JavaScript uses for its `number` type), integers above 9,007,199,254,740,992 can't all be represented; for instance, 9,007,199,254,740,993 and all odd numbers above it can't be represented by the format. (Go high enough and it's not just odd numbers, but ones that aren't evenly divisible by four.) That can matter when you have intermediate steps in calculations. If you use `bigint` instead, `3n**35n` and `3n**34n * 3n` both give you 50,031,545,098,999,707 (as a `bigint`).

Comment: More: [number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number), [bigint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Bigint)